# Why are GLM constructors all explicit?

Tags: c++, glm-math

I have started to use the GLM library in my code. Seems pretty good but I can't do things like this:

```
void foo (const glm :: vec3 & arg);

foo ({x, y, z});
```

because the constructors are all explicit.

This is starting to annoy the hell out of me. I can't think of a good reason to prohibit implicit construction of such simple value types. Have the authors blindly followed some irrelevant dictum or do they know something I don't?

Comment: how about `foo(glm::vec3(x, y, z))` or... maybe this syntax is the reason why they don't make another much explicit syntax (??)

Comment: Why are you asking *us* instead of the maker of the library?

Answer (score 3):

In the newest version he's added C++11; see the changes for 0.9.5.0 in the README

https://github.com/g-truc/glm

and download it at g-truc

http://glm.g-truc.net/

I just dropped it into my project and all seems to be well. The initializer lists are a welcomed addition.

Also, I'll agree that putting spaces around the :: makes parsing that signature a little difficult, at least for my brain.